# Angularjs ng-repeat with orderby

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I want to render data in asc order Objects of array using ng-repeat. Below one is array object.

```
$scope.Stepdetails=[{
        [{
             RequestId: 2024,
         name:aa
        }]
      },
      {
       [{
             RequestId: 2025,
       name:aa
        }]
      },
      {
       [{
             RequestId: 2023,
        }]
      }]

  <td ng-repeat="Steps in Stepdetails ">   

      <div ng-repeat="step in Steps| orderBy: 'Steps.step.RequestId'">
       </div>
   </td>
```

Comment: It looks like your model is incomplete. Also, please update your post to include which version of Angular you're using.

Comment: My model is right one.I'm using  AngularJS v1.3.2

Comment: Your model is invalid javascript object

Comment: I don't see any 'orderBy' expression in the ng-repeat API docs. Where did you get it? https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.2/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: @RobertoLinares it is a filter, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: I've updated JS object, it is right.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access array elements but your structure is an object, try changing stucture, something like:

```
$scope.Stepdetails=[    // Steps

        [{              // Step
         name:aa,
             RequestId: 2024,
        }]
      ,

        [{
         name:aa,
             RequestId: 2025,
        }]
      ,
        [{
         name:aa
             RequestId: 2023,
        }]
      ]
```

Comment: Yes I've changed, but how to sort in ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot order objects like this using the built-in orderBy filter. Before I get into that, your object doesn't look correct. It should be look like this:

```
$scope.Stepdetails =[{name: aa, RequestId: 2024},
                     {name: aa, RequestId: 2025},
                     {name: aa, RequestId: 2023}]
```

Back to the filtering, you will need to build your own filter to sort complex objects. This website has a great solution that is pretty much plug and play:

http://justinklemm.com/angularjs-filter-ordering-objects-ngrepeat/

Answer (score 0):

This seems very doable, but your object needs some work. @nairys has the object right:

```
$scope.Stepdetails = [
    { name: "aa", RequestId: 2024},
    { name: "aa", RequestId: 2025},
    { name: "aa", RequestId: 2023}
];
```

All you need to do is pass in `RequestId` since `name` is the same thing (in your example).

Consider:

```
<div ng-controller="StepController">
    <div ng-repeat="step in Stepdetails | orderBy: 'RequestId'">
        {{ step.name }}, {{ step.RequestId}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular orders automatically in ascending order. To order by descending, just add a `-` in front of the property you want. `orderBy: '-RequestId'`.

This is a simple order solution, but it's not going to work for multi-dimensional arrays. However, if you just want to order a simple array of objects this will work.